# Efficient GC collection with large heap of 30 - 100GB

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, java-7

Can Java 7 now handle large heap of 30 - 100GB efficiently without significant GC pause?

Comment: Java 7 is a language. Handling of a huge heap is a property of the implementation. That the reference implementation can't do it doesn't mean it's impossible with all other implementations.

Comment: @delnan: Java7 is a language *and* a new implementation of Hotspot, excessive pedantry aside. The question is perfectly valid.

Comment: @skaffman I think what delnan meant was Hotspot is not the only VM around. E.g IBM J9 is another implementation. Hotspot and IBM J9 have very different GC implementation and policies. So what is possible with one may not be possible with another.

Comment: Unfortunately buying Azul does not help. Azuls ingenious pauseless garbage collector needs operating system support, which will not happen until people put pressure on the vendors. Which will in turn not happen until many people know about this. :-(

Comment: Yes, i know that, buying Azul means buy their complete technology-stack. From the modified Linux-kernel, over their virtualization layer and to their JVM. The software piece of Azul Systems is really ultimate unique on the platnet. But as you sad, unfortunately not much people know about it.

Comment: simple answer is no, certainly not in any general case at least.  slightly longer one needs a definition of significant pause and your style of heap usage.

Comment: I have edited your question to only the parts that are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

There are tuning options available, and concurrent GC, but there will still be some pauses during the GC of the *tenured generation*.

Angelika Langer explains this in detail in this presentation:

http://vimeo.com/28761227

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Terracotta BigMemory. This is useful if you are storing objects in a big cache in heap. This is not open source but in my opinion, reasonably priced. BigMemory basically allocates object memory outside heap and hence the heap size can be kept to a minimum or medium size.